# Поиск индекса слова в строке

Tags: python

у меня к вам вопрос, у меня задание найти позицию проверочного слова "кот".
Длина строки - 50 символов, когда я разбивал строку при помощи split, кот стоит на 6 позиции.
Я не понимаю как можно найти слово "кот", т.к. перед ним слово "который".
Я ввожу искомое слово, но данный код работает только для слова "кот". Вопрос как его найти, в результате индекс должен быть равен 23. Благодарю Вас.

```
x = "У нас который год есть кот которого Васькой зовут."
y = input()
print("Слово началось с " + str(len(x) - x.rindex(y)) + " позиции" if y in x else "Слово не найдено")введите сюда код сюда код
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = "У нас который год есть кот которого Васькой зовут."
print(x.find(' кот ')+1)
print(x.index(' кот ')+1)
```

Результат:

```
23
23
```

Рекомендация: Перед тем, как задавать вопрос, откройте любой учебник по Python. Раздел со строками (ну, или с той темой, по которой вы вопрос задать хотите).

Comment: Вы знаете, нет не правильно. Есть y = input(), в котором я ввёл кот вашем случае получается значение "7". Благодарю вас.

Comment: обратите внимание на пробелы. 7 будет только если без пробелов сработает на 'который' . и если добавить пробелы по краям то выходит 23. проверяйте ещё раз

Comment: @Интик предлагаете вводить текст с пробелами, только чтобы сработал кривой код?

Comment: @Андрей Кривошеин Вам таки настоятельно надо  читать учебник!!! Обязательно.  На подсказках программирование не выучишь и специалистом не станешь. Иначе бы вы поняли, что на самом деле ввод вы должны сделать вот так:  y='   '+input()+'   ' (Между кавычками -  пробел)

Comment: @passant Да, конечно вы правы, просто зашёл в тупик. Благодарю вас

Answer (score 1):

Используйте лучше **регулярные выражения**:

```
import re

x = "У нас который год есть кот которого Васькой зовут."
y = input()
rx = re.compile(fr'\b{y}\b')
found = False
for z in rx.finditer(x):
    print(f"Слово началось с {z.span()[0]} позиции")
    found = True
if not found:
    print("Слово не найдено")
```

Шаблон `\b` означает границу слова. Так гораздо проще искать слова внутри предложения. Иначе придётся вручную проверять чем ограничено слово, оно может быть окружено не только пробелами, а ещё и знаками препинания и/или началом/концом строки. И все эти случаи придётся предусмотреть.

Comment: Ваш код - абсолютно правильный. Единственное, в чем я не уверен -  это в том, что еще не освоив работу со строками ТС может понять, как работать с регулярными выражениями.

Comment: @passant А кому сейчас легко... ))